# struts Action tag with tile result causing StackOverflowError- in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2, apache-tiles

I have upgraded my struts application to version 2.3.30 and apache-tiles 2.2.2 and I am facing issue with s:action tag and tiles result. 
it goes in recursive loop and throws `StackOverflowError` as below.

also I am able to reproduce this issue in showcase application, I have outlined the tiles.xml , struts-tile.xml and layout.jsp as below.

```
it throws java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:230) 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:230)
    .................. (truncated)
    .................
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.ActionComponent.executeAction(ActionComponent.java:288)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.ActionComponent.end(ActionComponent.java:172)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.tiles.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005faction_005f0(layout_jsp.java:210)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.tiles.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:109)
```

Here is my usage,

tiles.xml

```
<definition name="showcase.index" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Tiles Showcase"/>
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/header.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/body.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="showcase.index.actionResult" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/actionTileResult.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Tiles Result from action"/>
</definition>
```

struts-tiles.xml

```
    <action name="index">
        <result type="tiles">showcase.index</result>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">showcase.index</result>
    </action>

    <action name="myTestAction">
        <result type="tiles">showcase.index.actionResult</result>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">showcase.index.actionResult</result>
    </action>
```

Layout.jsp

```
<html>
    <head><title>Struts2 Showcase - <tiles:getAsString name="title"/></title></head>
<body>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>
    <p>Notice that this is a layout made in JSP</p>
    <!-- This action causing stackoverflow error --> 
**  <s:action name="myTestAction" namespace="/tiles" executeResult="true" /> **
</body>
</html>
```

actionTileResult.jsp

```
<tiles:importAttribute name="title" scope="request"/>
<html>
    <head><title>Action tile result <tiles:getAsString name="title"/></title></head>
<body>
    <p>Notice that this is a  jsp</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know anybody faced similar issue and any solution to it.

Comment: Solution `executeResult="false"`.

Comment: executeResult="true" required as that will  includes result within current page.

Comment: then remove result from the layout

Comment: @RomanC it was working without an error before upgrading to struts2 2.3.30. And also this is required as,  it's used to include dynamic result based on actions logic.

Comment: @RomanC the above code is to reproduce same error with struts showcase demo app, in actual application there are many exactly same usages.

Comment: Could you post url to the working version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128580/discussion-between-zaga250-and-roman-c).

Comment: Why do you use `<s:action>` tag?

Comment: s:action is used so that result can be included in the page.

Comment: Also with `<s:property>` you can include the result in the page... `<s:action>` tag usage is discouraged, consider refactoring the software to avoid using it, if the size of the application is not *leviathanic* ...